# Why is the date extracted from my Google sheet off by 1 day when used?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm extracting dates from a column in my Google sheet with Google Apps Script, and then printing it out in a message (e.g. "your subscription is expiring on 2/19/19").

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("San Diego"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var dataSet = sheet.getRange(StartingRow,2,lastRow-StartingRow+1,9);
var data = dataSet.getValues();

for (i in data) {   
   var rowData = data[i];
   ....
```

The dates on the sheet (in rowData[2]) are of the form MM/DD/YYYY or MM/DD/YY.

However, when I print the date (the variable ExpirationDate below) in a message, the date shown is 1 day earlier than in the sheet.

This happens with both:

```
var ExpirationDate = Utilities.formatDate(rowData[2],Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and

```
var ExpirationDateForCompareInt = new Date(rowData[2]);
var ExpirationDate = Utilities.formatDate(ExpirationDateForCompareInt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I thought the rowData[2], in the timezone designation, would be interpreted as the date in California (LA), if I'm reading the documentation correctly. I'm in the same timezone as LA.

Any idea?

Comment: Are both script timezone and spreadsheet timezone the same?

Comment: getScriptTimeZone() returns America/Los_Angeles.

Comment: spreasheet setting shows GMT-8:00, which is California time (the time in Los Angeles).

Comment: Try changing `Session.getScriptTZ()` to `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` in any case.

Comment: I go to the script's Project Properties and it shows GMT-08:00 as well, so spreadsheet and script have matching time zones.

Comment: [Edit] your question to quote both dates as seen by the  script using `Logger.log()`

Comment: Changing to ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() works! Thanks! Still not sure why it didn't work before though, if both timezones were the same.