# Why is the Google Sheets tab labeled with the previous day's date and how can I update it using Apps Script?

Tags: xcode, google-sheets, tabs

I want to have my sheet make a new tab based on the date. The code below works perfect, but the date it labels the tab with is a day behind. For example- if the date on the form/timestamp is 5/31/23, the tab is labeled 5/30/23. How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
function NewDay() {
  var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = -1
  var numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab = 60
  var rangeToClear = 'A3:M19'

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

  // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab *     MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy");
  var deleteWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - (numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab *  MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy"); 

  // Adds tab
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Copies current sheet
  ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
  ss.moveActiveSheet(2); //Moves sheet to the first position  
}
```

I have not tried anything as I know nothing about coding and the code above was from another person's question.

Comment: The issue relates to the difference between your spreadsheet timezone and your script timezone. I suggest that you read the comments on [Why is the date extracted from my Google sheet off by 1 day when used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54765128/1330560). Then try changing "GMT+1" to `ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` (as suggested by @TheMaster).